# Normal audio stops when jackd starts

Tags: linux, arch-linux, audio, pulseaudio, jack

Awhile ago I set up Pulseaudio and JACK to play nicely together on Arch Linux so I could switch between them. The problem is some JACK apps must be completely restarted when jackd is restarted, which makes it incredibly inefficient to try and alternate between let's say Google Chrome and MuseScore.

My goal is to get Pulse to route through JACK. It seems that this should be the case right now, as there are Pulse Sink/Source devices connected to system audio in JACK.

However, when I try to play audio on any website in Chrome or VLC (both routing to Pulse), it doesn't work.

- In VLC, the progress bar progresses but no audio comes out. If I start jackd in the middle of it, the audio comes from wherever the progress bar is at that point, so whatever audio was supposed to play was "dropped".
- In Chrome, tested with Google Play Music, YouTube, and HTML5 `<video>` and `<audio>` elements, the progress bar stays at zero or wherever it was when jackd was started. If I start jackd in the middle of it, it starts playing at that point, so no audio was "dropped".

How can I fix this?

Comment: the vlc issue is can be solved with help of [the arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/JACK_Audio_Connection_Kit#VLC_-_no_audio_after_starting_JACK) i guess.

Comment: Yeah, I usually use that. I just switched it to make sure it was a PA issue not a Chrome issue

Answer (score 1):

It is preferable to stop playback from all audio sources before starting JACK to avoid problems

Install pavucontrol standard Pulseaudio mixer - many panel controls and mixers for Pulseaudio do not show all available options, particularly sound device routing options.

Applications with audio problems are likely still trying to play direct to audio device normally used by Pulseaudio. If JACK has started and taken control of the audio device, pavucontrol has dropdown list of routing options to redirect audio from hardware device to the Pulseaudio jack sink.

Pulseaudio often only needs to have playback redirected manually one time for each application. The routing change is saved and Pulseaudio will *usually* switch automatically in future

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend installing Cadence from the [KXStudio repositories](https://kx.studio/Repositories) and have it Auto-Start Jack at login, including PulseAudio & ALSA bridges. Works fine for me.